# List of tables and list of figures Information aligned under the heading

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I have the problem that when I have a list of tables and or a list of figures, the information is shifted to the right. Is it possible to centre the information under the heading?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{array}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of plots}
}

\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Etiam lobortisfacilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultricesaugue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.  Vivamus nunc nunc, molestieut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.  Ut porttitor.  Praesent in sapien.  Loremipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

Duis fringilla tristique neque.Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.  Nam rutrum augue aleo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blanditmauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsansemper.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Pgfplot3d3}
\caption{Three dimensional graph.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pgfplots3dexample.png}
\caption{Second 3D plot.}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 \hline
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{First table.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Scattered}
\caption{Scatter plot.}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country Name    or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
 \hline
 Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
 Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
 Albania    &AL & ALB \\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
 American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
 Andorra & AD & AND \\
 Angola & AO & AGO \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Dummy table.}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | } 
  \hline
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
  cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Third table.}
\label{tab:table3}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper
\end{document}
```

Comment: Article.cls uses `\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}` and `\let\l@table\l@figure` where 1.5em is the indentation and 2.3 em is the space reserved for the figure number (see `\numberline`).

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you. But I use `report`. I did not know that would be important. That was just an example.

Comment: As it turns out, report and book use the same definitions.  It really doesn't matter if you want to try different values.  Don't forget about `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.  And use `\renewcommand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "centre the information under the heading". Do you want the list entries to be typeset centered with respect to the page or shifted to the left so that they align with the List titles. If the former I have no idea. If the latter then try this revision of your MWE (for which I thank you).

```
% lofcenterprob.tex  SE 633814

\documentclass{article}  % or report or book class

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% added
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{array}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of plots}
}

\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}



\begin{figure}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Pgfplot3d3}
THREE DIMENSIONAL
\caption{Three dimensional graph.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}%[h]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pgfplots3dexample.png}
SECOND 3
\caption{Second 3D plot.}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}%[h]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 \hline
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{First table.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}


Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.


\begin{figure}
\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Scattered}
SCATTERED
\caption{Scatter plot.}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}%[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country Name    or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
 \hline
 Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
 Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
 Albania    &AL & ALB \\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
 American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
 Andorra & AD & AND \\
 Angola & AO & AGO \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Dummy table.}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}


\begin{table}%[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | } 
  \hline
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
  cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Third table.}
\label{tab:table3}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper

\end{document}
```

In general the `tocloft` package is useful for fiddling with the "List of ..." elements.

I have also trimmed your MWE a little bit as the important things in the question are the appearance of figure and table captions in the LoF and LoT. You only need to provide one figure and table with no additional text to demonstrate the appearance of the LoF and LoT.

Comment: Thank you, when I use this, the list of figures and the list of tables are displayed under each other, not as I had before. Each on a new page. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: @Test. I processed your MWE and both lists were on the same page. Did you try it yourself? If you want them on separate pages then put `\clearpage` before `\listof...`.